# How to store an image as a profile pic of one user?

Tags: iphone

I'm beginner of iphone app development.I done an iphone app that it contains registration page,login page  and profile using sql database as a saving field.I want to keep a pic as profile pic.I done selecting a pic from already stored pics from simulator.I want to keep that   pic as it is when once again if I run that....plz help me...

Comment: Your images are not going to change, so why you do not store the name of the name for particular person and when you load the details once again just use that image name to display image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the image in Application bundle and can retrieve the image at the time of application load:

Here is a tutorial for you :

http://www.friendlydeveloper.com/2010/02/using-nsfilemanager-to-save-an-image-to-or-loadremove-an-image-from-documents-directory-coding/

Answer (score 0):

Use this when obtaining image of image selected from gallery by using imagepicker:

```
   -(void)saveImageInDirectoryAndStoreInDatabase
   {
     NSArray  *paths        = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imgFilePath  = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",youruserName];

     NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(youruserImage) //which is obtained from imagepicker
    [data writeToFile:imgFilePath atomically:YES];
     //query here into database with imageFile(A string) which is[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",youruserName];
   }
```

Similarly when retrieve image use documentDirectory+imageFile.png (which is obtained from database by querying user name with its imageFile) path to set user profile pic